# Running a Silverlight Website

Tags: silverlight, xaml, web

When using silverlight in a browser is there anyway to switch xaml pages? I'm also wondering  how to go about using my encryption class I've wrote in c# to validate users in silverlight. Any help would be much appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Silverlight 3 Beta then what you're looking for is the Navigation system using the Frame and Page controls. There are lots of tutorials available online for this.

In Silverlight 2 the easiest solution is to replace the RootVisual with a Panel (like Grid or Canvas) and have your own code to switch the child elements (which are usually your own UserControls).

There's a good tutorial available at [Flawless Code](http://www.flawlesscode.com/post/2008/03/Silverlight-2-Navigating-Between-Xaml-Pages.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

We are using Jesse Liberty's method of doing the page switching in SL2.  It is explained here. [Jesse Liberty SL2 page switching](http://jesseliberty.com/2008/05/31/multi-page-applications-in-silverlight/)

It also look or feels a lot like how SL3 does it with the Navigation mentioned above.

Caution:  If you do this, the back button on the browser will need to be handled - users will exit out of your SL2 app when hitting the back button.  SL3 has built in support for handling and responding correctly to the back button.